# How can I detect the presence of a Sony SmartEyeglass device?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I am writing an android app that will interface with a Sony SmartEyeGass. I want to detect the presence and connection of the device, prior to the user starting functions that use the glasses.

Unfortunately, I am having trouble reliably detecting if the device is present or not. Watching for the START, STOP, etc events is not solving my problems because I often get START events received by the `ExtensionReciever` when I start the application and the `ExtensionService`, despite having the glasses powered off. Running the `ControlExtension` that shows stuff on the glasses has no problems drawing onto nothing.

How can I get information from the SmartEyeglassAPI indicating whether the device is present or not? I have not been able to find this digging through their online documentation nor in the samples.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API as part of SmartExtensions to check whether the glasses are connected or not.  You should be able to detect whether the glasses are connected by listening for connecting Bluetooth devices and checking the device name.

This API may work for you:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html#getConnectedDevices()